# Adding default value to attribute when is nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add a default value to an attribute just when it is being created as a nested of another object?

I have the models/associations:

```
User has_many page
```

And I want to be able to set the attribute `found_in` of the model `Page` to the value `'user'` when the pages are created nested from within a User object.

I want that default value to just be when the pages are created as nested attributes of a User.

So, when I do

`User.create(pages_attributes:[{:url => 'test'}])`. I would like those pages to have a `found_in` default value of `'user'`.

Comment: you mean the relation isn't saved when u save the record? or something else?

Comment: It is saved, but the default value is not added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Page model:

```
before_save :set_found_in

def set_found_in
  self.found_in = 'user' if user.present?
end
```